# React-Native Dark mode didn't works :)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, alert

When I changing iOS theme to dark, alerts always are light. I need dark alerts. Please help!
I tried to use react navigation, but it isn't works :(

Comment: Can you post some of your attempts?

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with: `"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"`